# show child block under static block in home page in magento 2

Tags: layout, static-block, magento2.3.4, color-swatches

I want to show color swatches of configurable product in home page
But My all static blocks in  cms page.
Here is my static block

```
{{block class="Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList" name="latest" aspect_ratio="1" column_count="6" product_count="12" image_width="212" product_type="3" template="grid.phtml"}}
```

Here is my layout xml code which is working fine to display color swatches in home page but I want to show convert body part in static block.
Should I use `addchild()` method in `LatestList` block file ? If yes how ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <head>
           <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="homepage.swatchrenderer">
                <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>     

        <referenceContainer name="main">
          <container name="topproduct" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="topproduct">
                  <block class="Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList" name="productlist" template="Smartwave_Filterproducts::grid.phtml">
                      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="homepage.swatchrenderer" as="homepage.toprenderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                      </block>
                  </block>
           </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is my Block file

```
<?php

namespace Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class LatestList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

    protected $_collection;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }
      protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        
       $this->addChild(
            'homepage.toprenderers',
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList::class
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getNameInLayout() . '.homepage.toprenderers')
            ->addChild('default', \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class);

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getNameInLayout() . '.homepage.toprenderers')
            ->addChild('configurable', \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable::class);

        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();
        $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        if(!$category_id) {
            $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
        if(isset($category) && $category) {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite() 
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        } else {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        }

        $collection->getSelect()
                ->order('created_at','desc')
                ->limit($count);

        return $collection;
    }
      public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function getDetailsRenderer($type = null)
    {
        if ($type === null) {
            $type = 'default';
        }
        $rendererList = $this->getDetailsRendererList();
        if ($rendererList) {
            return $rendererList->getRenderer($type, 'default');
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function getDetailsRendererList()
    {
        return $this->getDetailsRendererListName() ? $this->getLayout()->getBlock(
            $this->getDetailsRendererListName()
        ) : $this->getChildBlock(
            'homepage.toprenderers'
        );
    }
    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }

    public function getProductCount() {
        $limit = $this->getData("product_count");
        if(!$limit)
            $limit = 10;
        return $limit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read your question and was keen to give it a go.. but really I don’t understand where you are at the moment and what is your issue..: put your block code maybe so that we can have same problem as you..

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy Actually I want to display color swatches in home page so I have porto theme so,Porto theme inject all statick blocks in cms page to display products in home page so I have a solution to display color swatches of configurable product in home page for that I have to declare block in layout xml file .I want to show color swatches of those blocks who declare as static block in cms home page

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy again ,If my all static block declare in cms page,that all static blocks display products in home page but issue is products not showing with color swatches so I got solution to display color swatches declare block and its sub block in layout xml file. QUESTION IS HOW CAN I DECLARE SUB BLOCK IN STATIC BLOCK LIKE ABOVE LAYOUT XML FILE ?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below does render some product swatches for the product in the listing.

```
     <?php

namespace Mbs\HomeProducts\Block;

use Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable;

class LatestList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return 12;
    }

    /**
     * <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
    <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/frontend/show_swatches_in_product_list" />
    </block>
     *
     * @return LatestList|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptioN
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->addChild(
            'details.renderers',
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList::class
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getNameInLayout() . '.details.renderers')
            ->addChild('default', \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class);

        $configurableRenderer = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getNameInLayout() . '.details.renderers')
            ->addChild('configurable', \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable::class);
        $configurableRenderer->setTemplate('Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml');

        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try and then let you know

Comment: you did not create this block    in block file
<referenceBlock name="homepage.swatchrenderer">
                <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: yes if possible but not mandaotry

Comment: it still not working but I appreciated your effort and bytheway I accept your answer

Comment: ok sure Please check in weekend,thanks again

Comment: I have updated my question and add block file code.please check it

Comment: my answer is now updated and it should be better than the previous answer I made

Comment: You did it bro ! you always rock bro thanks god bless you

Comment: I just changed my block name from 'homepage.toprenderers' to 'details.renderers' in getDetailsRendererList function and it works. you are master of M2

Comment: you made me smile, great questions from you yet again, thanks